# How many full time developers are working on Proof of Stake research?

Tags: proof-of-stake

How many full time Ethereum developers (or full time equivalents) are currently working on PoS research?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is several months old but may still be useful:
https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/10/18/vitaliks-research-and-ecosystem-update/

"Casper: Ethereum’s proof of stake algorithm now under development by Vlad Zamfir with help from Lucius Greg Meredith, myself and several others."

Depending on the definition of several other I am guessing there were at least 3 or 4 people spending a lot of time on it last fall. Over time more developer interest (not less) will probably focus on it.

Answer (score 1):

Tendermint is not specific to Ethereum, but its PoS solution will be compatible with Ethereum.  In fact, Ethereum is one of our target use-cases.

See https://github.com/gnuclear/gnuclear-whitepaper

Comment: Hi, while informative it does not contribute to the question directly, could you give a number how many devs are you fulltime-equivalent?